# GlassFish multiple EARs

Tags: glassfish

I have an EAR that I deploy as production, in context "/".
I'd like to deploy a test version of the application on the server, the same Glassfish instance.

Is it possible to deploy the application under a different context and port in the same instance?

If so, beside changing the context in application.xml, do I need to change anything else?

Comment: I want to do the same.  I was wondering if creating a new domain in glassfish with a new port etc could solve this problem?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Yes, a new domain is a different server see here for more about the concept of a domain in glassfish http://blogs.oracle.com/bloggerkedar/entry/concept_of_a_glassfish_domain

Comment: @Ittai, I've done that since.  Unfortunate an instance is not lightweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can deploy a test version of the application by altering the context root, and deploying it as a whole new application.

However, you must take the application's design into consideration. If the application utilizes a database, more often that not, you'll need a test database instance. All JNDI names (this includes datasources and EJBs, if any) that the test and production applications use, must not have any conflicts. It is an ill-advised move to run multiple instances of the same application, all of which reference the same JNDI names.

Finally, it is a standard accepted practice to separate your test and production environments, and even have separate machines for the same, in the case of mission critical apps and the like. This is done usually to prevent accidental overwriting of one environment (usually the production one) by another.

Comment: You're mostly correct, but there isn't any problem in itself to look up same jndi names in different app instances. For a jdbc connection, it will just take a connection from the pool whenever needed. I'm not saying it's a good idea: you would get a connection to the same db for test/prod. But that's not a jndi problem.