# Designing a pluggable app as multiple EARs in Java EE 6

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ear

I'm kinda new to Java EE 6 and most of what I'm reading is tutorial-oriented, simple cases.  I can't find an answer to pretty basic question, so looking to you guys for help.

I have a system I am designing to have pluggable components in a Java EE 6 App Server (Glassfish v3).  There will always be a core (deployed as an EAR), and then a series of pluggable components that may or may not be deployed on any given app server, each one of which is packaged as an EAR itself.

Is this a reasonable design?  Will transactions work across EJBs that are live in separate EARs?  Can EJBs in one ear send JMS messages that are consumed by MDBs in another EAR?

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324256/glassfish-multiple-ears) was inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will transactions work across EJBs that are live in separate EARs?**

[Yes but you need to use JTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987326/can-i-use-jta-over-different-ears-which-are-deployed-to-different-servers)

**Can EJBs in one ear send JMS messages that are consumed by MDBs in another EAR?**

Yes and that is the whole point of message queuing.